# Consulta SQL para gestionar dia inicial y dia final del mes completo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ojalá me puedan apoyar en la siguiente consulta de *SQL* que estoy realizando para obtener el día inicial y final de un mes completo, aunque no sea el mes en curso.

Ya tengo casi terminada la instrucción solo que no puedo hacer que funcione tomando el mes completo, es decir, si el mes trae 31 solo me está tomando 30 días.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @Fecha DATE = getdate() 
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH , -6,DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@Fecha) + 1, @Fecha))
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(MONTH , -5,DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@Fecha) -0, @Fecha))
print @StartDate
print @EndDate
```

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar esta tarea puedes Utilizar [EOMONTH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**LA SOLUCIÓN:**

```
DECLARE @Fecha DATE = '2020-12-18'
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Fecha, -1)) as diaInicioMes, EOMONTH(@Fecha) AS diaFinalMes
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la función `EOMONTH()`

```
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE())  --devuelve la fecha con el ultimo dia de ese mes
SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(day , 1 , EOMONTH(GETDATE())))
 --agregamos un día,  
 -- entonces se convertirá en el primero del próximo mes, después restamos un mes 
 -- entonces será el primero del mes en curso
```

Comment: Gracias por la informacion pero estoy utilizando SQL2008R2 y aparentemente esa funcion no funciona en esa version... =(

Comment: Disculpa copie mal el código, intenta de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el inicio y fin de mes de una fecha cualquiera, puedes valerte de la función [eomonth()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), de *end of month* (fin de mes).

El fin de mes es trivial, simplemente le pasas cualquier fecha y te devuelve la fecha del fin de mes de esa fecha.

Para el inicio, puedes utilizar la misma función, en esta ocasión pasando un `-1` como segundo parámetro, para obtener la fecha de fin de mes del mes anterior y, finalmente, a esta sumarle un día para obtener el primer día del mes que te interesa.

En código sería algo como:

```
declare @Fecha date = '20160617';

declare @InicioMes date, @finMes date;

set @InicioMes = dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(@fecha, -1));
set @finMes = eomonth(@Fecha);

print @InicioMes;
print @FinMes;
```

Esto imprime:

```
2016-06-01
2016-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto.

```
DECLARE @myDate DATE='2019-07-02'
--obtiene el primer dia del mes
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0)  AS date)AS [Inicio del mes]

--Obtiene el ultimo dia del mes
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@mydate)+1,0)-1 AS DATE) AS [Final del mes]
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada muchas gracias a todos por sus tips, he logrado generar la consulta justo como la necesito, la adjunto por si a alguien le sirve.

```
   -- para consultar el mes de junio
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate =  DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) 
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)))
print @StartDate
print @EndDate

----mayo
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate =  DATEADD(mm,-2,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) 
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)))
print @StartDate
print @EndDate
```

y asi por cada mes que necesiten consutar...